# Proof that the composition of two contractions on the same metric space (X,d) is also a contraction

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

I am required to prove that given the metric space $(X,d)$, a contraction  $T : X \to X$ and another contraction $S : X \to X$, the compositions $T \circ S$ and $S \circ T$ are also contractions.

I started by assuming $Ct$ and $Cs$ the constants of the contractions for $T$ and $S$ respectively.
 For $S \circ T = S\ Tx$:

$d(Tx, Ty) \leqslant Ct\cdot d(x,y)$. I know that now I have to apply $S$ to this inequality, but I'm kind of stuck here.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Hint: start with $d(STx, STy) \leq C_s d(Tx,Ty).$ Can you go on?

Comment: Yeah, I think you're right. If I start this way, I can go one step further with the inequality and say that  d(STx,STy)≤Csd(Tx,Ty)≤CsCt*d(x,y). Having C = CsCt in(0,1), now I have that d(STx,STy)≤C*d(x,y). And it should be done, right? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, for all $x,y \in X$: $d(S \circ T(x), S \circ T(y)) = d(S(T(x)), S(T(y)) \le C_s \cdot d(T(x), T(y))$ (applying the property for $S$ for $T(x)$ and $T(y)$) $\le C_s \cdot ( C_t \cdot d(x,y)) = (C_s \cdot C_t) \cdot d(x,y)$.

This shows that $S \circ T$ is a contraction with constant $C_s C_t < 1$ (if both $C_s, C_t < 1$).

The exact same constant can be found for $T \circ S$, applying, using the essentially same argument.